# JavaScript - Unable to Get Form Input Value

Tags: javascript

When the user enters text in the text field and clicks the submit button their text should come up on the screen. Right now nothing shows.

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/itotub/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function myOnloadFunc() {
    var inputAnswer = document.getElementById("inputAnswer");
    var userAnswer = inputAnswer.innerHTML;

    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

    submitButton.onclick = function() {
        document.write(userAnswer);
    };
}

window.onload = myOnloadFunc;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="inputAnswer" placeholder="Enter your answer">
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value=">">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `input` element does not have any descendants, so `.innerHTML` returns an empty string. If you want to get the value, you have to access the `.value` property (for more info, see the [`HTMLInputElement` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement)).

Another problem is that you are trying to get the value *before* the user actually typed in anything. You don't want to get the value on *page load* but when the user *clicks the button*:

```
submitButton.onclick = function() {
    console.log(inputAnswer.value);
    // or alert(inputAnswer.value);
};
```

---

I would refrain from using `document.write`, even if it is only for testing purposes. At least [understand what happens when you call it after the DOM was loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write#Notes).